# Sequelize insert only if item belongs to owner

Tags: sql, authentication, express, web, sequelize.js

I am making an auction site using node/express sequelize ORM.

I want to insert an item in the auction table only if the item belongs to the current logged in user.

Is there a better way to achieve it than the following?

**/api/listings**

```
var models = require('../../models');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.route('/:id')

    .post(function(req,res){

        // get all items belonging to logged in user
        // for item in items array
        //      if (item.itemID == req.params.id)
        //          models.Listing.create({...})
        //      else
        //          res.json("You can't list that item")
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JWT for authentication attach the userId to the token, then decode the token on the request and find the current user id and make sure that the items user id equals the user id passed in the header/token.